# Subtract two cells from two different workbooks in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I opened two excel sheets and sorted them based on a column that is similar for all three. That portion of the code works and is good. Now I need to refer to two cells in two different workbooks and subtract them. I had a set of loops that was complex but I kept getting errors so I stripped it down to a basic subtraction function. With this script now the message box is displaying "mprice_delta" rather than a numeric value. I don't know what I did but it worked once and then reverted back to displaying a text answer rather than numeric.

```
Dim objTPG, objTPG_prior

Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objXL.Visible = True
objXL.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objTPG = objXL.Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath & "TPG.csv")

Const xlAscending = 1
Const xlYes = 1

Set objTPGSHEET = objTPG.Worksheets(1)
Set objRange = objTPGSHEET.UsedRange
Set objRange2 = objTPGSHEET.Range("E2:E9999")
objRange.Sort objRange2, xlAscending,,,,,, xlYes

Set objTPGPRIOR = objXL.Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath & "TPG Prior.csv")
                                                                                                                        'REMEMBER TO MAKE SHEETS RUN IN BACKGROUND
Set objTPGPRIORSHEET = objTPGPRIOR.Worksheets(1)
Set objRange = objTPGPRIORSHEET.UsedRange
Set objRange2 = objTPGPRIORSHEET.Range("E2:E9999")
objRange.Sort objRange2, xlAscending,,,,,, xlYes

Set objEXPO = objXL.Application.Workbooks.Open(FinalExposure)

Set objEXPOSHEET = objEXPO.Worksheets(1)
Set objRange = objEXPOSHEET.UsedRange
Set objRange2 = objEXPOSHEET.Range("I2:I9999")
objRange.Sort objRange2, xlAscending,,,,,, xlYes


 Function mysub(x,y)
mysub = x - y 
 End Function

Dim mprice_delta
mprice_delta = mysub(objTPG.Cells(2,10).Value, objTPGPRIOR.Cells(2,9).Value)
MsgBox(mprice_delta)
```

Answer (score 0):

objTPG is a workbook

You need to use a worksheet to access the cells.

Maybe objEXPOSHEET and objTPGSHEET?  I'm not really sure of your code